# Remove overlapping values in coordinates lists

Tags: python, list, image, image-processing, coordinates

I have an image that is `1920 x 1080`, and corresponding co-ordinates that represent bounding boxes on that image with random shapes of (x,y).

```
bb_rects= [[412, 130, 507, 234], [521, 82, 647, 188], [521, 314, 747, 469], [820, 372, 943, 473]]
```

I am trying to extract 100 x 100 images from the `1920 x 1080` that are not within those bounding boxes in `bb_rects`. I applied brute force over the `1920 x 1080` image with a window extracting `100x100` co-ordinates every 100th step. How can I exclude coordinates in `all_rects` that overlap with the coordinates in `bb_rects`?

```
all_rects= [(0, 0, 100, 100), (100, 0, 200, 100), (200, 0, 300, 100), (300, 0, 400, 100), (400, 0, 500, 100), (500, 0, 600, 100), (600, 0, 700, 100), (700, 0, 800, 100), (800, 0, 900, 100), (900, 0, 1000, 100), (1000, 0, 1100, 100), (1100, 0, 1200, 100), (1200, 0, 1300, 100), (1300, 0, 1400, 100), (1400, 0, 1500, 100), (1500, 0, 1600, 100), (1600, 0, 1700, 100), (1700, 0, 1800, 100), (1800, 0, 1900, 100), (0, 100, 100, 200), (100, 100, 200, 200), (200, 100, 300, 200), (300, 100, 400, 200), (400, 100, 500, 200), (500, 100, 600, 200), (600, 100, 700, 200), (700, 100, 800, 200), (800, 100, 900, 200), (900, 100, 1000, 200), (1500, 900, 1600, 1000), (1600, 900, 1700, 1000), (1700, 900, 1800, 1000), (1800, 900, 1900, 1000)]
```

The output should be `rects_filtered` which are `all_rects` co-ordinates that do not overlap with `bb_rects`.

Answer (score 1):

So, what came to my mind: the concept is to build kind of a "grid" and determine which squares are actually fully-contained in any of bb_rects. Not sure if it's any better in terms of processing time, but you might want to try this:

```
import math

bb_rects= [[412, 130, 507, 234], [521, 314, 747, 512]]


def does_rectangle_contain(rect1, rect2):
   return rect1[0] <= rect2[0] and rect1[1] <= rect2[1] and rect1[2] >= rect2[2] and rect1[3] >= rect2[3]


for rect in bb_rects:
    min_x = int(rect[0] / 100)
    max_x = math.ceil(rect[2] / 100)

    min_y = int(rect[1] / 100)
    max_y = math.ceil(rect[3] / 100)
    possible_overlapping_rectangles_y = range(min_y * 100, 100 * (max_y + 1), 100)
    possible_overlapping_rectangles_y_pairs = []
    for first, second in zip(possible_overlapping_rectangles_y, possible_overlapping_rectangles_y[1:]):
        possible_overlapping_rectangles_y_pairs.append((first, second))

    possible_overlapping_rectangles_x = range(min_x * 100, 100 * (max_x + 1), 100)
    possible_overlapping_rectangles_x_pairs = []
    for first, second in zip(possible_overlapping_rectangles_x, possible_overlapping_rectangles_x[1:]):
        possible_overlapping_rectangles_x_pairs.append((first, second))

    possible_rectangles = []

    for a in possible_overlapping_rectangles_x_pairs:
        for b in possible_overlapping_rectangles_y_pairs:
            possible_rectangles.append([a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1]])

    print(possible_rectangles)

    for grid_rect in possible_rectangles:
        if does_rectangle_contain(rect, grid_rect):
            print(f"fully contained: ({grid_rect[0]}, {grid_rect[1]}, {grid_rect[2]}, {grid_rect[3]}) in "
                  f"({rect[0]}, {rect[1]}, {rect[2]}, {rect[3]})")
```

For my test data it yields:

```
[[400, 100, 500, 200], [400, 200, 500, 300], [500, 100, 600, 200], [500, 200, 600, 300]]
[[500, 300, 600, 400], [500, 400, 600, 500], [500, 500, 600, 600], [600, 300, 700, 400], [600, 400, 700, 500], [600, 500, 700, 600], [700, 300, 800, 400], [700, 400, 800, 500], [700, 500, 800, 600]]
fully contained: (600, 400, 700, 500) in (521, 314, 747, 512)
```

You can later out simply filter out 'all_rects'.

**Note**: the code shall be refactored, of course. It's just a rapid prototype.